# Array in postgres with text values when inserting them gets wrapped in double quotes ("")

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I wanted to use the `SELECT ARRAY['foo','bar','foo bar','foo,bar','foo.bar']` and the output of it to insert into a field with datatype of `text[]`. But the out ut of the above `SELECT ARRAY` query gave me a strange response where the text with spaces/commas were present it wrapped them in double quotes. Any help how to get data without double quotes.

[image: Array with various type of texts]

I have tried with ARRAY_AGG function too still the same response

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-IO) this is the text representation of an array. Everything is OK

Comment: nothing wrong with this. It is just the text representation of an array in postgres :)